# Dspace and SOLR configuration

Tags: solr, dspace

I would like to add `ommitNorm=true` to the title field.

It is wrongfully overboosting some of our titles.

However I don't know how the title field is indexed. What is its name - just dc.title?

Because in the schema.xml, I don't see anything about it. What is the type of that field, what analyzer or anything else is used for it. Is there anyway to know?

Answer (score 1):

Most metadata fields in DSpace are handled via dynamic fields. That's why you don't see each specified individually in the search core's [schema.xml](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/solr/search/conf/schema.xml) file.

I'm not sure where the boosting is happening (or whether DSpace does any, even). I don't recall seeing any boost clauses when looking through the solr log files. I see some extraction parameters being set in [SolrServiceImpl#writeDocument](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/discovery/SolrServiceImpl.java#L702), where the document is being indexed. It looks like there is an extraction parameter for boosting individual fields, perhaps you can play with that to get what you'd like.

If you want to see the field type for any Solr field, the easiest option is probably the Schema Browser in the Solr admin user interface, eg
http://localhost:8080/solr/#/search/schema-browser?field=title (you may need to use an SSH tunnel or the like to access Solr running on a different host since the DSpace solr install is typically IP-limited to access from localhost).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will have a look. However at the same I do not think it is a boost added, what I am thinking about is the natural field normalization. I would like to do something special for the title and remove the option of field normalization. Although I could not figure out the dynamic field (rule) for title.

Comment: If you figure it out, be sure to post your own answer to this question -- I'm sure there are other DSpace users out there who'd be interested in this. You might like to ask on the dspace-tech mailing list too, maybe someone else has already figured out a solution.